# How to properly quit application, call exit(0)?

Tags: cocoa, application-shutdown

I'm not sure which is the right way, right now I'm just calling `exit(0)` when a user clicks on the exit button.

Comment: Don't forget to title your button “Quit”, not “Exit”.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `NSApplication`'s `terminate` method. For example:

```
[NSApp terminate:self]
```

Documentation is available [here](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/terminate:).

Answer (score 6):

The previously given answer is deprecated since 10.10 and this question is the first thing that turns up for *cocoa quit application*, so use this instead (Swift):

```
NSApplication.sharedApplication().terminate(self)
```

**Note:** As of now it's the following:

```
NSApplication.shared().terminate(self)
```

Comment: What's deprecated? The use of `NSApp`? `NSApp` still appears to be available and isn't marked as deprecated in the documentation…

Comment: Because I just had to do this again: the original way to do it now yields:
`static member 'sharedApplication' cannot be used on instance of type 'NSApplication'`.

PS: Note that I wrote the comment above when Swift was still quite unstable, and especially Xcode was quirky as hell. So the error message might have been different at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I always terminate App the safe way.

```
[NSApp performSelector:@selector(terminate:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

This will put the event in the next loop.